# JAVA Dynamic List Type

Tags: java, list

Is it possible to make a method return a dynamic List type. Such as a method a(Object b) can return a `List<Integer>` when the b is Integer type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note that you're asking about *dynamic* attributes. Don't forget that generics implement [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). That is, at runtime, a `List` is simply that. The generic hints are there simply for compile time.

So what you would be returning is a simple *raw* `List`. It doesn't have type information with it and a `List<Integer>` is identical to a `List<Double>`.

There's no reason why you can't implement an interface like:

```
List<T> getList(T param);
```

but that's a static definition and you have to implement particular types in your codebase.

Comment: I'm asking this question because there is a warning if I return raw List type. Thanks anyway.